# Peewee select where(True or (True and True)) is not working

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I am woorking with Peewee to select books. I want to select books based in the type.
When searchen or looking at peewee´s instructions I have not found any help.

See the below example where I wish to select all books that is `Pocket` or `Hard_cover` and `threaded` that is not working:

```
Books.select(
    ).where(
        Book.title.contains("Some title")
    ).where(
        Book.type == "Pocket" |
        (
            Book.type == "Hard_cover" &
            Book.binding == "threaded"
        )
    )
```

Selecting `Pocket` works, but it won´t select any `Hard_cover` and `threaded`.

**Note:** I have tried not having () after the else | then selected nothing.

Comment: I have yet to found a sollution for the query. What I will do is to wrap the call in an interface that performs 2 database calls and returns a list with the found books.

Answer (score 1):

Because of PYthon operator precedence, you need parentheses:

```
).where(
    (Book.type == "Pocket") |
    (
        (Book.type == "Hard_cover") &
        (Book.binding == "threaded")
    )
)
```

Documentation is clear: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_operators.html